# remove single quotes from array output

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array defined like this in Python.

```
keys = "setid","cntrct_id","version_nbr"
```

and the elements are pushed into array as expected.

```
print(keys)
('setid', 'cntrct_id', 'version_nbr')
```

But when am trying to insert quotes and split the elements with ',' seperated

am getting output like this

```
'"setid","cntrct_id","version_nbr"'
```

am expecting output like this:

```
"setid","cntrct_id","version_nbr"
```

I tried many ways,

```
(','.join('"' + x + '"' for x in keys))

','.join(map(lambda x: "\"" + x + "\"", keys))

','.join(['"%s"' % w for w in keys])
```

but everything is appending single quotes,

How should I avoid generating single quotes from output?

Comment: `keys` is not an array, it's a tuple

Comment: try printing your results, you'll see that the quotes are gone. They are the result of the _representation_ of the string in the python REPL

Comment: You appear to be confusing the data structure with its string representation. You can get the output you want with `','.join('"{}"'.format(x) for x in keys)`, if you really do want a simple comma-separate list of quoted words.

Comment: first eval is evil, then there is no problem at all. The quotes aren't there. The _representation_ of the string adds them (representation is here to debug the result, not to print it) @nixon

Comment: keys = "setid","cntrct_id","version_nbr"

am looking for this result exactly,

df_full_01.join(df_cdc_update01,["setid","cntrct_id","version_nbr"],"leftanti")

but if I add quotes seperated by comma its returning like this:

df_full_01.join(df_cdc_update01,['"setid","cntrct_id","version_nbr"'],"leftanti")

Answer (score 1):

I think the `'` is just from the Python shell and not really part of the string itself. Have a look at the following example:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test_string = "hello"
>>> test_string
'hello'
>>> print(test_string)
hello
>>>
```

Comment: yes, it is. But it's also a duplicate.

Comment: Also I need to return this string to calling function, and while returning the array element its throwing single quotes.